# Advice about what kind of data structure to use for quick search times C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am currently in the thinking process of the data structure I might use for a current project. I don't need to delete items as i am loading a database,using it, and then exiting the program. The only constraint concerns search time.(memory in a second time but mainly time).

Overview on what I intend to do.
I am parsing files and extracting informations that I use to create various object.
After reading the files and creating the objects,i have a set of multiple objects that have references to other one as string.

**The goal here is to find which net goes from one domain to another**

E.g : text input file :

```
module Blabla 
netTomodule Foo
domain 1
..../*Other parameters of the module*/
end module

module Foo 
netTomodule Blabla
netTomodule Foo2
domain 2
..../*Other parameters of the module*/
end module

module Foo2
netTomodule Foo
domain 2
..../*Other parameters of the module*/
end module
```

After reading this I get 3 module objects Foo Foo2 and Blabla and their attributes are as follow :

```
class Module{
private :
string name;
int domain;
netlist * mynetlist;
...
}
```

**My opinion and the thing i want to get advice on :**

After thinking about this, i think that my best shot is to :

1. When reading the file and extracting info, i should create a linked list of Module.
2. Then with the number of Module i have read, i create an array that is double the size of that.
3. For each module, I use a hash function to hash the module name and put a pointer to this module at the given index in the array
4. Now when i will want to find a module, i just have to compute the hash value and get the pointer at the given index(or increment if its not the good module because of a collision previously in the making of the array)

This is basically an implematation of a hashtable or atleast what i know of a hashtable from my clasess.

My question is **Is this a good thought ? Is there a hashtable library i can use that does that ?** (i have heard and look for unordered_map and map but i don't know if it fits my needs very well)

This is a huge text so i hope it is detailed enough, so thank you if you have the courage to read everything !

Comment: It is hard to understand your question because there is a lot of irrelevant information and repetitions in it. Try concentrating on the essential and avoid empty phrases (“The things you should know is that …”).

Comment: It is difficult to answer without knowing what operations you want to perform with your modules. What is the overall problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have edited to make it clearer that The goal here is to find which net goes from one domain to another (ie there is a net netween Foo and Blabla that crosses domain from 2 to 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use any hash table that comes with your standard library or from [boost](http://www.boost.org). Most will have the `unordered_map` (as specified by TR1 and proposed for C++0x) as does boost, but some will have a `std::hash_map` or `stdext::hash_map` with various implementation being slightly different, e.g. the original SGI vs. Microsoft.

You don't need to build a list, just put the objects directly in the hash table; it allows sequential iteration, though it will be in some fixed random order.

Comment: Hi, i think that is what i am going to do. I was mislead by what we did in C class where the teacher told us about knowing the number of element for a hashtable initialization. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you can maintain a hashtable (string => pointer to object of type Module) instead of a link list.

Again inside the class Module, again maintain a hashmap or a map of string => pointer

Comment: I was told in class that to make a hashtable i had to know the number of elements that would be in it(to have a hashtable that is twice the size). This is why i said in the OP that i created a linked list to count the number of elements and then go throught it to compute a hash value. // Is that untrue ? can i directly use the hashtable to put stuff in it ?

Comment: @djfoxmccloud: Every reasonable hash table will automatically resize. The `unordered_map` does and all other `hash_map` implementations that come with standard libraries I've seen so far did as well.

Comment: @djfoxmccloud : I just suggested a solution. As far as counting the number of objects is concerned, even to do that, you do not have to create a link list. You can count them on the fly while you are reading the files to create module objects. So once you have all the objects created, you are aware of the size. Same goes with the nets (or links within module objects), you will be aware of the size when you get the closing tag 'end module'

Comment: Once created, the objects have to be placed in some container. So either they will be placed straight in the hash map, or they have to be placed in a temporary container.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in indirect relationships as well (`Foo2`->`Foo`->`BlaBla`) you essentially have a graph. In that case you could use [Boost.Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/index.html).

Comment: Thank you but i am only interested in non transitive relationship !